# Prevent controller from creating new scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing a custom scope object to the `$compile` and creating a custom template. If I apply a directive on the elements inside the template, scope that is changing is the one that is passed to the `$compile`, and that's really what I wanted.
However, I just thought that it might be good to also have a controller on some elements inside the template,

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName" >
</div>
```

but ng-controller doesn't set data on the passed scope but creates its own and uses that one. Is there a way to make ngController to use existing scope and not create a new one ?

Comment: controllers create a child scope that prototypically inherits from the parent

Answer (score 1):

We create our controllers and wrap them in factories to make them accessible. We apply or controllers through directives (also going away). This gives you a controller that is scoped to the directive, which has better control for scope, this works for us as the directives where we do this for are usually components.

I don't know if this will be an option given the road you are down now. I would suggest trying to stop using ng-controller. You may want to look at angular 2 now just to keep it in mind as a migration path, it is coming in the fairly near future. They have removed ng-controller, a lot of what they are doing in angular 2 can be done now.

This is a good resource on why these things are a bad idea

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI&t=9m10s

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code for `ng-controller`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L229), you will see it is very simple:

```
var ngControllerDirective = [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500
  };
}];
```

You can actually create an almost identical alternate directive that just defines `scope: false` (or omits the `scope` key altogether, same thing):

```
app.directive('controllerNoScope', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500 // same as ng-controller
  }
});
```

(*You may want to give it a better name*).

See [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B7Kn9RPFkhn3uj3jCq0S?p=preview) for a demo that shows the scope has the same `$id` as the outer one, meaning it is the same scope.